# Fetch : authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

When I request this, everything is ok and I get the data:

```
const get_players = async()=>{
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/player_stats/api/players/')
    const data     = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
}
```

But when I put **permission_classes** in views.py, I recive this in the console:

```
{detail: 'Authentication credentials were not provided.}
```

I am a beginner in Javascript so I wll hope you can understand.
I dont know how to put the **authentication credentials** in my fech.

**Views.py**

```
class PlayersView(ModelViewSet):             
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        serializer_class = PlayersSerializer
        queryset         = Players.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        queryset   = Players.objects.all()
        serializer = PlayersSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset   = Players.objects.all()
        qs         = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = PlayersSerializer(qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('players',views.PlayersView,basename='players') 

app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [    
    path('',include(router.urls)),           
]
```

Any idea?

Comment: You've added a constraint that someone needs to be logged in to use that api endpoint, have you tried logging in?

Answer (score 0):

The user behind the browser that runs the fetch needs to be authenticated, ie. logged in. There are multiple ways to do it. Refer to:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

But basically, `SessionAuthentication` will use Django's user login system, and if you want access the API without logging in, you can use `TokenAuthentication` in which case, you need to add an HTTP header to your fetch request.

```js
const get_players = async() =>{
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/player_stats/api/players/', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Token ${apiToken}`
      }
    })
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your view class tell us that you cant access this page unless the user is authenticated (logged in), i suggest in case you are using django default auth (session auth) getting the cookie that stored in local storage like this : `localStorage.getItem('csrf')` and then set the session id:
`localStorage.setItem('session_id',res.data.session_id)`(this is just a dummy example, i have no idea how you set your session id in the backend) when you receive a response in the frontend, or if you are using token auth (like jwt), you should add to headers :  `headers: {'Authorization': Token ${apiToken}}`
, one of the great jwt modules for drf and that easy to use with different endpoints is `drf-simplejwt`, more info: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

on a side note : i would not suggest using django default authentication, since it is hard to deal with, especially on the frontend side